# Send logs to log stash without writing to log files in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elastic-stack, elk, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

Is there any way to send logs to ELK (log stash) without writing to log files in spring boot using log back configuration

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just don't want to write to log files (but are still using spring boot and logback), then you can use the TCP or UDP logback appender provided by [`logstash-logback-encoder`](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) to send logs to logstash's `tcp` or `udp` input.

Example logback configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
      <destination>logstash-host:4560</destination>
      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="logstash" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Example logstash configuration:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 4560
        codec => json_lines
    }
}
```

See the logstash-logback-encoder docs for more appender and encoder options.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a auditDocument kind of thing which will have below parameters and than push it to ELK...

Parameters :
Req ID,
Req BODY,
Res BODY,
API Called,
Method
etc..(as per your requirement)