# Sending logs to datadog using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, datadog

I was reading this question: [Send logs to log stash without writing to log files in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190239/send-logs-to-log-stash-without-writing-to-log-files-in-spring-boot) and I'm wondering if I can do the same sending all my log stuff to Datadog site from Springboot.
Has anyone did this successfully or has a published example to follow?
Thanks in advance.